# Cross Origin error. Is it grunt file configuration?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

My app structure looks something like this

```
 -client
    - dist
    - directives
    - services
    - controllers
    - partials/ 
          state1.tpl.html
          state2.tpl.html
    - index.html
    - app.js
    - bower_components
        - angular.js
        - jquery.js
        - etc
    - Gruntfile.js
```

As you must have noticed.. there is nothing fancy above.

In order to compile everything and put it in a destination folder, I wrote a simple GruntFile which looks like below:

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

```
clean: ["./dist"],

copy: {
    main: {
        src: ['src/index.html', 'src/**/*.tpl.html'],
        dest: 'dist/',
    },
},

concat: {
    options: {
        seperator: ';'
    },
    css: {
        src: ['./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', './css/app.css'],
        dest: 'dist/app.css'
    },
    jquery_lib: {
        src: ['./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'],
        dest: 'dist/jquery_lib.js'
    },
    angular_lib: {
        src: ['./bower_components/angular/angular.js', './bower_components/angular_ui/build/angular-ui.js', './bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js'],
        dest: 'dist/angular_lib.js'
    },
    app: {
        src: ['./src/app.js', './src/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'dist/app.js'
    }

},
```

});

```
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'concat', 'copy']);
```

So the gruntfile does its work and creates file in the dist/ folder.

Now my index.html looks like below:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    {{test}}

    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>

    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="../jquery_lib.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular_lib.js"></script>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
</body>
```

when i click on state 1, the browser gives me the following error:

```
angular_lib.js:9732 XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
file:///Users/james/Documents/Code/bk/client/dist/src/partials/state1.tpl.html. 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

any clude why I am getting this error ?

Comment: What paths are you using for your templates? Angular is trying to load them using file:// rather than http:// , this would make me think you may have file:// in your router config, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem by having the index.html served by an http server rather than telling the browser to read it directly from the file system.  As you can see in the browser output you posted, CORS isn't supported by the `file://` protocol, but it is supported by the `http://` protocol

Eg, if you have Python installed, there is a simple http server you can run from the same directory as the `index.html` file:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

After you run that from the same directory that index.html is in, visit `localhost:8000` in your browser.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Created a express server .. this however lead to another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219638/express-file-not-serving-app

Comment: looks like it got solved :)  I struggled for a while getting Angular running too.