# express file not serving app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

my express file looks something like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var conf = require('./conf');

var app = express();


/*********** start server ************/
http.createServer(app).listen(conf.port, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + conf.port);
});


/****** Serving Static pages  *********/
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/dist/src/'));
```

The dist folder looks something like this:

```
   dist/
     jquery_lib.js
     angular_lib.js
     app.js
     src/
       index.html
       partials/
          state1.tpl.html
          state2.tpl.html
```

When I visit

```
 http://localhost:12345/index.html
```

in the browser, the browser is unable to locate

jquery_lib.js, angular_lib.js and app.js
index.html refers to these files as below:

```
<script src="../jquery_lib.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular_lib.js"></script>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
```

Any clues why the browser is not able to locate these files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express.static()` only serves files out of the base directory you pass to it. If you were able to break out of the base directory and access parent directories/files, that would be a big security breach.

So put your `jquery_lib.js` and `angular_lib.js` files inside `src/` somewhere and update your html `src=` values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
  app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/assets')));
```

Now by doing this the benefits you are going to get is, in your html or whatever template engine you are using , you can just put your files in public/ assets and refer to it as 
`src = "assets/xyz/abc.js"`.

In that way it becomes very easy to manage the public libraries.